# Many tables or one big table with horizontal partitioning

Tags: mysql, database-partitioning

I'm design database for new project. I need to create a custom multi-chat system but I have a question: many tables (one for one chat) or one big table with horizontal partitioning ? My database is mysql and the chat are isolated each other.

I ask this because the project may potentially have many chat.

Comment: Even without understanding your vague question:  the answer, in almost all circumstances, is one big table.

Comment: one table. they are isolated if written correctly. think of TurboTax multi-tenant. all the data is combined in as few tables as possible, even tho we can't see each other's tax data.

Comment: Just go with one table to start with, you can change it later on if you need too. Don't scale/optimise too early.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't be afraid of large tables. I am using a partitioned table with 1.5 billion records. By using the right indexes the performance of queries and views is still split second. I agree with the isolation  remarks of the other contributors.